# How could my mutation from apollo client get 400 error, while I can do that from playground?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have the following mutation that works in the playground.

```
mutation UpdateBoolean($newValue: Boolean!, $id: Int) {
  updateOneSetting(data: { darkMode: $newValue }, where: { id: $id }) {
    id
    darkMode
  }
}

// variables: {"id": 1, "newValue": false}
```

However, it doesn't work when I do the same thing from my apollo client on react, showing the error: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400`.

```
const UPDATE_BOOLEAN = gql`
  mutation UpdateBoolean($newValue: Boolean!, $id: Int!) {
    updateOneSetting(data: { darkMode: $newValue }, where: { id: 1 }) {
      id
      darkMode
    }
  }
`;

const ToggleLabel: React.FC<ToggleLabelProps> = (props: ToggleLabelProps) => {
  const id = 1;
  const [mutation] = useMutation(UPDATE_BOOLEAN);

  const onChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    checked: boolean
  ) => {
    console.log(checked); // true
    mutation({ variables: { newValue: checked, id: id } });
  };
  ...
`;
```

I'm totally not sure what the error indicates? Could anyone give me a suggestion?

**EDIT:**
The error is:

```
Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.ts:46)
    at Object.error (QueryManager.ts:255)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:140)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:240)
    at observables.ts:15
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (observables.ts:15)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:140)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:240)
    at httpLink.ts:184
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the reason your request is failing by either examining the response from your server in your browser's dev tools, by inspecting the `error` object returned by the hook, or by inspecting the rejection reason by calling `catch` on the Promise returned by calling `mutation()`. The last one you should be doing regardless so that you can handle any errors resulting from executing your operation.

That said, the reason your request is failing is because you've got a variable defined but it's not being used (`$id`). Any variables you define as part of your operation need to be used at least once within that operation.

Comment: I forgot to change the line, but **I knew even if I omit the dollar signs I will get the same error**. Also I have attached the error provided by `catch` in the edit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot because it's a network error, neither the hook result nor the error inside the catch are going to be super informative. Just take a look at the request response in dev tools like I suggested -- the response will include an `errors` array with details about what went wrong.

Comment: Also, just noticed the other issue with that query -- you've got an used variable, which will also result in a validation error.

Comment: OK now I got it. At first, I used `$id` in the mutation and put `$id` in the mutation call. Then because it didn't work, I hard-coded the `id` in the mutation, **which caused another error** (but I didn't notice). After that I changed the `$id` to `id` in the call and forever wondering why it didn't work. Now the difference of the errors is clear through the dev tools. Thank you so much!